# How to create a function with postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to run this command according [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-declarations.html)
but it always returns 1, i.e. not the number of rows that I want

```
CREATE FUNCTION getQuantity() RETURNS integer $$
   select count(*) from table;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

select getQuantity();
```

Does anyone know if I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: You are not returning anything. Where's your `RETURN` statement?

Comment: @WEI_DBA you mean put return select count(*)... or save the select statement in a variable and return it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a keyword `as`. Also, `count(*)` returns `bigint`, so:

```
create function get_quantity() 
returns bigint as $$
   select count(*) from my_table;
$$ language sql;
```

or

```
create function get_quantity() 
returns integer as $$
   select count(*)::int from my_table;
$$ language sql;
```

[Test it in dbfiddle.](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=09ee81fd1157a3a45ce2158c04cc17b0)

Comment: Still return one yet, I try both

Comment: Both functions work as expected, see the link in the modified answer. Maybe you should drop an old version of the function: `drop function get_quatnity()`.

Comment: Yeah, after I drop it worked. It's something like cache in browser